# Unchecked Input for Loop Condition (Excessive looping validation for long)

Tags: java, loops, validation

I've a class in which we are storing "amount of time between two temporal objects" into a long variable monthBt  and using it as Test Expression in "for loop". However I am getting medium level security warning "Unchecked Input for Loop Condition" in azure sechub.

```
long monthBt = MONTHS.between(YearMonth.from(startAndEndDate);
for (int i = 0;i<= monthBt;i++) {
//do something
}
```

what is the best way to validate and remove the warning?
Thanks!

Comment: Because you are comparing a loop control of `int` against a `long` - the warning is likely saying "since the long could be greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` it is possible the loop control will never meet the terminating condition and be an infinite loop".  Either change the loop control to a `long` or (realistically) change `monthBt` to `int`.

Comment: Thanks @Gardener. How have tried both ways i.e. 1)change the loop control to a long 2) change monthBt to int but still the getting the medium level security warning.

Answer (score 0):

Gardner is absolutly rigth so do this:

```
int monthBt = (int) MONTHS.between(YearMonth.from(startAndEndDate));
        for (int i = 0; i <= monthBt; i++) {
            //do something
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @xthe_white_lionx.However i am still getting medium level security warning.

Comment: wrong use of `Month.between()` needs to arguements see signature `public long between(Temporal temporal1Inclusive, Temporal temporal2Exclusive)`